# Finding sup(S) and inf(S)

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Am I doing this right?

1. S={$(-1)^n$|n$\in$natural numbers}
   I got that
   S =\begin{cases}
   -1,  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
   1, & \text{if $n$ is even}
   \end{cases}
2. S={$(-1)^n$n|n$\in$natural numbers}
   I got that
   S =\begin{cases}
   -\infty,  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
   \infty, & \text{if $n$ is new}
   \end{cases}

Comment: Why are there so many questions about finding sup and inf these days?

Comment: @Zero It's the beginning of the school year and this is a very basic problem in real analysis.

Comment: S={$(-1)^n$n|n$\in$natural numbers} then s={-1, 2, -3,...} not as you said.

Comment: oops. I meant to put -1, if n is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supremum and infimum of a set are numbers, when they exist; you can tell from this *a priori* that your answers can't be correct. ($\sup S$ is never a case statement, as you've given -- it's either a number, or else it doesn't exist).

For 1), note that $x \leq 1$ for all $x \in S$. Further, $1 \in S$. These together imply that $\sup S = 1$. The same argument shows that $\inf S = -1.$

For 2), the important point is that for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $x \in S$ with $|x| > N$. This implies that $\sup S$ does not exist, and similarly for the infimum.

Comment: And then if $x_n$=$(1.5)^n$ for all n$\in$ natural numbers, would inf(S) be 1.5 and sup(S) not exist since it just keeps increasing?

Comment: @ematth7 That's completely right.

Comment: and so I wouldn't be able to find the $lim supx_n$

Comment: @ematth7 Not quite. Knowing that $\lim \sup S$ is equal to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ is not quite the same as not being able to find it; you have understood something about the behavior of $S$ if you can say something like that, and some authors will allow $\sup$ and $\inf$ to take extended real values (i.e. $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty,-\infty\}$). This stands to reason, since making the statement that "$\sup S = \infty$" is saying a lot more than "I don't know $\sup S$". Whether the infimum or supremum "exists" in these cases is left up to semantics, and it doesn't really matter how you say it.

Comment: @ematth7 to be complete, I'll add that in the case you described, $\lim \sup x_n$ and $\lim \inf x_n$ are both $\infty$, which is fine, and better than saying that we can't find them.